# How do I copy workspace URL in slack application for windows?

Tags: user-interface, slack

How do I copy workspace URL in slack application for windows?

I tried to read manual and google about how to find slack worspace URL in windows client application, but the only link I have found is https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/221769328-Locate-your-Slack-URL and it doesn't provide information about how do I copy the workspace URL to migrate to another machine.

I think it would be very awkward to make screenshot and then use OCR to copy the text of the Slack Workspace URL link to another machine. Especially if the workspace URL is very long and if I need to migrate many workspaces to different machine.

I am definitely missing something, there should be a way to do this simply.

Also I am not administrator of these workspaces, so I can't use option to change workspace url to copy the link.

Comment: The URL of a Slack workspace is always `https://team-name.slack.com`

Comment: Could you please elaborate how your question is related to programming and therefore relevant to Stack Overflow?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken my question is more related to user interface of the application commonly used by programmers. Also I could reformulate it as : can I write a script which would export as a text file all slack workspaces I am currently logged in

Comment: OK. Well I think its an interesting question, but since its not really about programing it would fit better here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can you migrate this question to webapps?

Comment: however, slack is not a web app. it is desktop app

Comment: I mean there are both version, but my question is about desktop app

Comment: good point. Maybe superuser then? I think I can vote for migration

Comment: what is the main purpose of superuser?

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: sounds reasonable to move it to superuser. Is there an automated process to move some question with answer to superuser or should the question be migrated manually by opening a new question in superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like the trick is not to try copy the link, but start copying the workspace name, in such way it is possible to copy the URL as well.

[image]

Comment: I can't believe finding the unique identifier is so non-obvious. After my phone was destroyed, I'm trying to figure out how to add channels back into the phone. I have them on the computer, but unable to identify them by their url.